# PHP echo, how it's produce the output?

Tags: php

Please explain how echo understand the dot(.) with mathematical expressions and binary comma(,).

```
<?php

echo "The Sum: " . 2+3;

?>

//Output

3
```

Why 3 as output?

Comment: this is because "The Sum: " . 2 is converted to integer which is 0

Comment: @Chetan there is two operator dot(.) and plus(+) and dot has high priority than plus(+).

Comment: Use echo "the sum:" . (int)(2+3)

Comment: Question is why 3, not how to output correctly.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` and `+` are left-associative, so your statement is interpreted as

```
echo ("The Sum: " . 2) + 3;
```

This is equivalent to

```
echo "The Sum: 2" + 3;
```

When you add a string and a number, it converts the string to a number, which tries to find a number at the beginning of the string. Since `"The Sum: 2"` doesn't begin with a number, it converts to `0`. So that makes the statement equivalent to

```
echo 0 + 3;
```

which simplifies to

```
echo 3;
```

and that's the result you see.

Comment: Logical and correct answer.

Comment: They have the same precedence, the are just left-associative, that is the exact reason

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for the clarification, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is two operator dot(.) and plus(+) and dot has high priority so . try this

```
<?php
     echo ("The Sum: " . 2) + 3;
 ?>
```